# Intent on wifi signal strength change

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi

I want to open my app when my wifi signal gets below 20%
How do i implement this??
below is the code for wifi signal strength

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
      int rssi = connectionInfo.getRssi();
        int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, 10);
        int percentage = (int) ((level/10.0)*100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to write a small service that periodically checks for signal strength, and opens your app once the 20% level is crossed.  Beware of excessive battery use with something like this.

Comment: There's some good sample code for Services in ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LocalService.java and ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.java as well as  detailed descriptions of Services and some code snippets at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html .  I suggest starting there and then writing in with additional questions as you go